# Java: Class-type parametrized by interface implementations

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have an interface

```
interface I {}
```

and two implementations thereof, `class A implements I {}` and `class B implements I {}`
Now I would like to write a generic method which accepts a class-type parameter bounded by "Implements interface I", e.g.

```
boolean <T> isOK ( Class<T extents I> cl ) {
    switch ( cl ) {
       case A.class: return true ;
       case B.class: return false;
    }
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: by the way there is no need for `T` -- the declaration `boolean isOK ( Class<? extents I> cl )` would be equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like:

```
public <T extends I> boolean isOK(Class<T> cl) {
   ...
}
```

The qualifiers for the generic type go at the point the generic type is declared, which is the first triangular brackets, not the second.

Also you can't switch on a `Class`, you'd have to use something else to examine it, such as an `if` statement.